# Angular How to fallback to error from successfull subscription?

Tags: angular

I have this code:

```
  this.someService.someFunction(options).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response === 'xxx') {
        // do something
      } else {
        // fallback to the err callback
      }
    },
    err => {
      // how to get here from above success subscription? 
      console.log(err)
      ...DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT HERE
    }
```

The subscription is successful but after checking value I would like to fallback to the error callback so I can do some default handling for either success that does not meet criteria or error with the api call. `throw new Error()` does not work as it just show console error but won't fall to the error callback.

Comment: Create Separate method for handling error and call that method from both success and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Common method for error handling and call that function from both response and error callback function.

```
this.someService.someFunction(options).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response === 'xxx') {
        //Do Something here
      } else {
        //Here err is just temp variable. you can pass anything as per your requirement
        this.handleError(err);
      }
    },
    err => {                 
      this.handleError(err);
    }

//Common method to handle Error
handleError(err){
     //doSomething here.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once it reach the success function, it will never reach out to your error function, simple because it can't. What you should do is check the error in your `pipeline`, not from the `subscribe` function. I use [mergeMap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) for this case :

```
this.someService
    .someFunction(options)
    .pipe(mergeMap(x => x == 'xxx' ? of(x): throwError('x is wrong, go to error')))
    .subscribe(...)
```